# Use an xbox controller with MAME for light gun games?

Tags: controllers, emulation, windows, mame

How do you use an Xbox 360 or generic USB controller for MAME light gun games?

The sensitivity is too high and the gun cursor always goes back to the center of the screen when you release the control stick.

I've noticed when you use a keyboard it does not return to center. This makes the arrow keys on the keyboard the only way to play these types of games.

I've searched google and various forums for days trying to find a solution.

Some have mentioned an option to reduce sensitivity for analog controls which should help but I can't find it on my version of MAME .185

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In MAME's "Configure Machine" -> "Device Mapping" settings change the "LightGun Device Assignment" from Keyboard to Mouse. Trying to use Keyboard or a Joystick is near impossible beyond the first level of any game. You can change this per game or for all games.